# split this sql query so it can run on php as it does on workbench

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This query runs fine on MySQL workbench but not when I run it on PHP, what am I doing wrong?

```
  $q = "SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts p1
        LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta wm1  ON (wm1.post_id = p1.id AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL AND wm1.meta_key = "_thumbnail_id")
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm2 ON (wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id AND wm2.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file" AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL)
        WHERE p1.post_status="publish" AND p1.post_type="post" AND p1.ID in ('800','808', '569')
        ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC";

   if ($result = $conn->query($q))
   {
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
       {
           // SHOW three specific posts
           printf("Title: %s\r\n",$row['post_title']); echo "<br><hr>";
           printf("Content: %s\n",$row['post_content']); echo "<br><hr>";
```

Comment: Please provide the error that you're getting when you run the code with PHP.

Comment: i don't get nothing at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating your string with double quotes, you need to escape all the other double quote in your query:

```
$q = "SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts p1
        LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta wm1  ON (wm1.post_id = p1.id AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL AND wm1.meta_key = \"_thumbnail_id\")
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm2 ON (wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id AND wm2.meta_key = \"_wp_attached_file\" AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL)
        WHERE p1.post_status=\"publish\" AND p1.post_type=\"post\" AND p1.ID in ('800','808', '569')
        ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC";
```